# how to draw line using setShapeType in apache poi XSSF usermodel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

I'm updating the code to use 3.8 poi, so I'm changing the code from HSSF to XSSF. I have setShapeType to OBJECT_TYPE_LINE in HSSF, how to change the setShapeType for XSSF usermodel.
I need to draw a line using XSSF.
Here is my code,

```
XSSFDrawing patriarch= (XSSFDrawing) sheet3.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor regionr = patriarch.createAnchor(0, 0, 1, 1, (short)6, 12, (short)8.95, 12);
XSSFSimpleShape region1Shapevr = patriarch.createSimpleShape(regionr);
region1Shapevr.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
```

Thank you

Comment: excuse me, i don't get, what's the problem with the code above?

Comment: It doesnt create anything...it just gives me a blank rows without line

Comment: are you sure? i have tested it and it gives me a blue line in bottom of 12th row, from the beginning of G to the end of H rows

Comment: Hi, i did some changes and Im able to create a line,but Why it gives a thick blue colored line? whereas with HSSFPatriarch it gives a blank normal line

Comment: i don't know, maybe the default behaviour is different...